# how to set edittext input type to positive integer or positive decimal?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have already tried this but it has not worked:

```
android:inputType="number"
android:digits="0123456789."
```

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you're looking for the input type int. Or TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER.

```
android:inputType="int"
```

A list of all of the input types can be found at:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType